# How to Create Wallet for Website

Tags: wallet

I want to create a Wallet for website, i.e., for each individual user who register in the website.

How can i do this.

How to transfer coins from one wallet to another wallet

Answer (score 1):

A good phrase for this is "If you need to ask, you shouldn't." because there is just so much that can go wrong and not to mention wallet services are vast and abundant. But if you really want to: http://coinpunk.org/

Comment: Agree. Should further note that you should not be tempted to adapt the Brainwallet.org code to suit your needs either - unless you want to lose all you coins.

Comment: If you agree, why wouldn't you upvote the answer? o.0